# Facebook application - server not responding

Tags: facebook, iframe, authentication

After the FBML problems I switched to iFrame apps. All well for now except that 2 things:

1) if I did not entered in the app for a few hours and I try to enter, sometimes it gives me the error page that my server did not responded. It shows the Faceboob page with iFrame inside showing the error. After 1 or 2 refreshes it's working fine.

2) I implemented the new SDK with login like this

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $fbID,
  'secret' => $fbSecret,
  'cookie' => true,
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();   

if ($user) {
  try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    d($e); 
    $user = null;
  }
}

if (!$user) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                 top.location.href = '$loginUrl';
          </script>";
    exit;
}
```

The problem is my first redirect, when user enters for the first time. It redirects to my server URL not my Facebook app URL. If I try to put it like this:

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
    array(
        'redirect_uri' => 'http://apps.facebook.com/xxx/'
    )
);
```

the login is entering in an infinite loop.

Any help solving this two problems is welcome:-)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Darko4spain  when the user is redirected back to your site, you can detect if is in iframe with javascript and send them back.  I have same issue with my app.  This is not a pretty fix but it works.

---

```
if (window!=window.top) { 
//FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();
setTimeout("FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow()", 1400);
}else {
top.location.href = 'https://apps.facebook.com/AnotherFeed/?ref=redirect#comments';
}
```

---

example:  https://anotherfeed.com/plugins/index.php  will redirect you back to my canvas if you are not in the canvas.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. Your solution is not exactly what I need by you pointed me to the right direction. The thing is that mu users enter to the app with links like myapp.com?id=123456&lang=en and stuff like that. So instead of I always redirect them to my main URL Y will lose all the parameters. So, I was thinking of trying now is a replace string and just change www.server_url.com/ with www.fb_app_url.com/ so I keep the parameters and then do the redirect.

Comment: What I also noticed is that this (facebook redirects to the canvas URL) only is happening for my old FBML applications that I converted to iFrame. All the new applications that were created directly to iFrame are working fine (the redirect is going to www.app.myapp.com)

Comment: you can use javascript or php to catch the parameters, and you will not be able to redirect to any domain but your own.  Not even Facebooks.